# html agility pack issue in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I want to get link,title and price from this html(this is one result of ten results)

```
 <div class="listing-item">

        <div class="block item-title">
            <h3 id="title">           
                <span style="direction: ltr" class="title">
                    <a xtcltype="S" xtclib="listing_list_1_title_link" href="http://dubai.dubizzle.com/motors/used-cars/ford/explorer/2013/7/1/ford-explorer-2012-new-model-expat-leaving-2/?back=ZHViYWkuZHViaXp6bGUuY29tL21vdG9ycy91c2VkLWNhcnMv&amp;pos=1">FORD EXPLORER - 2012 - NEW MODEL - EXPAT LEAV...</a>
                </span>
            </h3>
    <div class="price">
                    AED 118,000
                    <br>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Here is my code

```
 var allCarResults = rootNode.SelectNodes("//div[normalize-space(@class)='listing-item']");
        foreach (var carResult in allCarResults)
        {
            var dataNode = carResult.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='block item-title']");
            var carNameNode = dataNode.SelectSingleNode(".//h3/a");
            string carName = carNameNode.InnerText.Trim();
        }
```

This give me object reference issue to get carName.What mistake i am doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataNode.SelectSingleNode(".//h3/a");` tries to select a `<a>` node directly under the `<h3>` that is somewhere under that `dataNode`.

However, in your case there is a `<span>` inbetween. So use `dataNode.SelectSingleNode(".//h3//a");` (note the `//` between h3 and a) to get an `<a>` node somewhere below a `<h3>`.